# Android Studio : Set Constraints for Layouts in Wear Apps

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, wear-os

When a new Wear OS App is created the activity_main.xml defaults to BoxInsertLayout. Unlike the more familiar ConstraintLayout the default does not allow constraints to be set for the various elements

It can be changed to the more familiar layout however several steps are required

Firstly from the design screen right click and then select
Convert FrameLayout to ContraintLayout
Select OK and wait for the Gradle Build to complete

Now left click the FrameLayout to select it and delete

Now right click and then select
Convert BoxInsertLayout to ContraintLayout
Select OK

Now you can insert elements and set constraints for them

Corruption

There remain problems - randomly Android Studio will move all your elements to the top left hand corner [[For example]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ochRN.jpg).

If you are lucky then it may offer a rebuild option however other times you need to manually try to restore the layout.

The issue is often all the elements will also have been made so small you can't select them from design view. To select one use the Component Tree (under the palette on the left).

Once selected set the Width and Height Attributes (on the right) to something large enough so you can click and drag the constraints using the Design View.

No it shouldn't happen - but it does

Comment: I was updating the .kt file, flicked back to the .xml file and watched as all the items jumped from their set positions to the top left hand corner! I did not change any files Android Studio just decided to move them all and will not allow me to move them back.

Answer (score 0):

It simply worked for me first time, just needed a dependency on

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
```

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that "implementation" was in the working version and missing from the broken version. Unfortunately adding it to the gradle did not fix the problem.